# Strange seeds on my English Boxwood

Tags: boxwood

I notice my English Box becoming yellowish. There are also round looking rounded outgrowth near the stems. Any idea what are these? Should I get rid of them?

[image]

Comment: Any time you see something like this, round up the usual suspects. Any insect? Any fungus? Any unusual weather hot or cold, wet or dry? Anybody spraying whacky chemicals nearby? Herbicides, fertilizer, paint, etc. Have you done anything unusual to it, like trimming, fertilizing, etc.? Get one of those little balls and cut it open with a magnifying glass and see if it is seed, insect egg, fungus ball, etc.

Comment: No sign of insects or fungus, according to my local gardening megastore, they said those round things are the seeds